WinApi: RegQueryValueEx returns application's filename
i've got an issue in the following code: RegQueryValueEx() returns the program name which is "WindowsSetup.exe".
TCHAR uninstallPath[MAX_PATH];
DWORD dwSize = MAX_PATH;
DWORD dwType = REG_SZ;

HKEY edge;    
if (!RegOpenKeyW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\Microsoft Edge", &edge)) {
    if (!RegQueryValueEx(edge, L"UninstallString", 0, &dwType, (BYTE*)&uninstallPath, &dwSize)) { ReportError(); return; }
}
else {
    ReportError();
    return;
}
MessageBox(0, uninstallPath, 0, 0);

MessageBox() displays "WindowsSetup.exe".
Does anyone know how to fix this? I'm trying to get the MSEdge UninstallString from the registered applications.

Remove the ! before RegQueryValueEx

In addition to @AlexF's suggestion, RegQueryValueEx() doesn't return a BOOL like most Windows API functions, but it returns the error code directly. (Which is why a return value of 0 indicates ERROR_SUCCESS, i.e. success.) Also, MAX_PATH is probably a bit short for an entire command line, and your code doesn't handle ERROR_MORE_DATA correctly here. Furthermore you have to provide the function with the number of bytes of your buffer, not the number of characters.

Do not open a WOW6432Node key directly. Open the non-wow64 key normally, but specify the KEY_WOW64_32KEY flag to let it redirect to the wow64 key

Do not edit a question's title to add SOLVED. I have reverted that change. The correct way to indicate a question is solved is to accept an answer. If there is no answer, you can post your own.

Use the Windows Installer API if you can instead of reading random values out of the registry.

@IInspectable Its Microsoft Edge, you cannot uninstall it, ill opt in for running it as NT AUTHORITY\System and manually removing the regsitry entires and Edge's files.

The things I did wrong:
Using (BYTE*)&uninstallPath instead of (BYTE*)uninstallPath
dwSize should be set to sizeof(uninstallPath) instead of MAX_PATH.
Correct code is:
 TCHAR uninstallPath[MAX_PATH];
 DWORD dwSize = sizeof(uninstallPath);
 DWORD dwType = REG_SZ;

 HKEY edge;    
 if (RegOpenKeyW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\Microsoft Edge", &edge)==ERROR_SUCCESS) {
     if (RegQueryValueEx(edge, L"UninstallString", 0, &dwType, (BYTE*)uninstallPath, &dwSize)!=ERROR_SUCCESS) { ReportError(); return; }
 }
 else {
     ReportError();
     return;
 }     


(BYTE*)&uninstallPath and (BYTE*)uninstallPath yield the same memory address. In the first case, the address of the array and the address of its 1st element are guaranteed to be the same. In the second case, the array decays into the address of the 1st element. Also, if RegQueryValueEx() fails, you are leaking the HKEY that RegOpenKeyW() opened. Also, be aware that the string read by RegQueryValueEx() is not guaranteed to be null-terminated, so consider using RegGetValueW()
